# Check array syntax with Regex

Tags: regex, dart

I'm trying to create a regex that checks if a string is a valid path for Firestore document.
I will find a regex that testing if a string:

1. start with a char `^([a-z]{1})`
2. after first char, there will be only letter/digit and/or a dot `\w*(.?\w+){0,}`
3. last chars in the string could be an index of an array `(\[{1}\d+\]{1})?$`

First and second points work well but the last group doesn't work. 
I test a string like `data.images[11` and the regex return true.

Comment: You need to escape dot (`.`) with a backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you can shorten some quantifiers in your regex:

- `{1}` -> can be ignored completely
- `{0,}` -> `*`

Your second part could be expressed like this, this will also support readability:

`[\w.]*` meaning: take any character inside the brackets 0 to n-times. The bracket expression also supports predefined classes, so we are using `\w` here. The dot INSIDE the brackets doesn't need to be escaped, it simply means the one character dot.

So your parts would be:

1. `^([a-z])`
2. `[\w.]*`
3. `(\[\d+\])?$`

I hope this helps. According to [regexpal](https://www.regexpal.com/) it matches `data.images[11]`, but not `data.images[11`. Also it seems to support all your demands.

EDIT:

Your second part doesn't work because (like Asocia stated in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945577/check-array-syntax-with-regex/61949135#comment109562287_61945577)) you would need to escape the dot. The dot itself is a class meaning "any character" (depending on regex engine and settings sometimes even line breaks). As you mean the dot as a character you need to escape it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
Sorry but I don't understand why if the second part is wrong the third doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I edited my post to answer that. Kindly note that Asocia correctly solved your one issue